# Server 2008 R2 - NAS for file storage

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, network-attached-storage

I currently have 2 Server 2008 R2's running in 2 separate locations.

All files currently reside on these servers and are replicated between each other over VPN via DFSR and it has worked for us for a while now.

We are however very quickly running out of storage.

I am thinking of purchasing an external rackmount NAS to incorporate into the network however here is where it gets a bit confusing for myself.

How does the server know that the files are located for users on the NAS (I understand I can use group policy for folder redirection for users etc pointing to a "home folder" on the NAS) and more importantly how does folder permissions work on an external NAS rather than a HDD within the server as as far as I know each NAS has it's own users?

This may sound like a rather dumb question but I'm sure a quick explanation from someone would clear things up.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a NAS.

You want an external drive array, which you can add drives to and connect it to the main server with a SAS cable. The storage will then be available for use on the main server without needing to perform any logistical gymnastics to get things working.

Comment: After a quick google i think that's the exact thing! I knew someone with the know how would be able to clear things up in a matter of seconds! Excellent mate. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Have a great weekend.